# Expose environment variables with different name in Dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm creating a Dockerfile for a container that will contain an application based on ASP.NET Core 2.2.

To take advantage of the environment variables via the .NET configuration system, I have to use a certain format but this makes the environment variables pretty ugly.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY src/ ./
RUN dotnet publish App/App.csproj -c Release -o /out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build  /out ./
ENV NYBUS_ENVIRONMENT=Production

ENV NYBUS_LOGGLY__APIKEY=loggly \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__Connection__Hostname=host.docker.internal \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__Connection__Username=guest \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__Connection__Password=guest \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__UnackedMessageCountLimit=

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "App.dll" ]
```

I was trying to use parameters but they don't seem to work

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY src/ ./
RUN dotnet publish App/App.csproj -c Release -o /out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build  /out ./
ENV NYBUS_ENVIRONMENT=Production

ENV LOGGLY_APIKEY=loggly \
    RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME=host.docker.internal \
    RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest \
    RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest \
    RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_LIMIT=

ENV NYBUS_LOGGLY__APIKEY=${LOGGLY_APIKEY} \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__Connection__Hostname=${RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME} \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__Connection__Username=${RABBITMQ_USERNAME} \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__Connection__Password=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD} \
    NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__UnackedMessageCountLimit=${RABBITMQ_MESSAGE_LIMIT}

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "App.dll" ]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is because the ENV is only evaluated at Build time, and not re-evaluated at runtime. So if you re-configure the "LOGGLY_APIKEY" ENV variable, it simply won't change when you launch the image.

If you want to have them evaluated and copied at runtime, you can use a shell script wrapper. Create a start.cmd, copy it in at build time, and then change your entrypoint to use the start.cmd file as the first argument.

```
set NYBUS_Nybus__RabbitMq__Connection__Hostname=%RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME%
.... Other set values ....
shift
start %*
```

Your dockerfile will have an entrypoint of:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "start.cmd", "dotnet", "App.dll" ]
```

Comment: It works when I run the container on Windows, now I have to translate it so that it runs in a Linux container! but thanks a lot :D

Comment: It’s the same approach but you make a start.sh. Ensure you “chmod 777 start.sh”. I’ll edit the answer to add a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Try ARG instead of ENV for the short names.

Comment: Isn't ARG for build arguments?